# spring cloud stream rabbit custom error handler and republishToDlq not work together

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have a custom error handler and republishToDlq is true but message in dlq is a reject-ed one not a republished, missing  x-exception-stacktrace etc.

I would like to use my own error handler and republishToDlq together, because I need x-exception-stacktrace

How can I do this? Or instead of my custom error handler (send email, audit etc) should I use interceptor?@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = "*error*")?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default.error-handler-definition: myErrorHandler
      function.definition: personSave

      bindings:
        personSave-in-0:
          destination: personSaveRequest
          group: personSaveRequestGroup
          content-type: application/json

      rabbit:
        bindings:
          personSave-in-0:
            consumer:
              autoBindDlq: true
              deadLetterExchange: nest.dlx
              deadLetterQueueName: nest.dlq
```

```
@Bean
public Consumer<ErrorMessage> myErrorHandler() {
        return errorMessage -> {
                        //email, audit etc
            log.error("Some error: {}", errorMessage);
            ReflectionUtils.rethrowRuntimeException(errorMessage.getPayload());
    };
}
```

Comment: I am not following. You are showing custom error handler where you can do anything you want. Am I missing something? You have not configured it, but that's a separate issue - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_handle_error_messages

Comment: Actually never mind, that's a formatting issue, i see its configuration now

Answer (score 0):

So, you can either use system error handling (DLQ) or your own where you can do anything you want, including manually sending message do DLQ via `RabbitTemplate` for example.

I am wondering though what and why you would expect that you custom error handler would somehow recognise your DLQ configuration? They are not related on any way. All the error handling mechanisms described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling) are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for the answer! My use case is sending email and writing audit log when error happen and system error handling is ok, dlq processing. Should I use @GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = " * error * ") for this?

Comment: What's wrong with the approach of custom error handler? Channels are internal detail that in theory may change without notice or its naming. That is why we removed all references to the word 'channel'  from the docs and provided a reasonable alternative . So, I would certainly not recommend GlobalChannelInterceptor